# Calling the templated function of a derived type

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14, decltype

I am attempting to call a templated function on the value but I want to call the templated version of the function that is from the potentially derived type. It is being determined that the type is `Dog` during the `typeid` but any attempt to cast is coming up short. How can I call the derived types templated `WriteData` function?

About the example

1. The `WriteData` function is templated even though the value is not used in this example as I made a small example.
2. It is not always know that the `Array` parameter will be an `Animal`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Writer {
    void Write(char* data) {
        cout << data << endl;
    }
};

template<typename Type>
struct Array {
    Type Data[2];

    template<typename Formatter>
    void WriteData(Formatter formatter) {
        cout << "Data[0](typeid): " << typeid(*Data[0]).name() << endl;
        cout << "Data[1](typeid): " << typeid(*Data[1]).name() << endl;

        Data[0]->WriteData(formatter); // "Animal is doing something"
        Data[1]->WriteData(formatter); // "Dog is doing something"

        auto data1cast = reinterpret_cast<decltype(Data[1])>(Data[1]);
        cout << "data1cast(typeidformatter " << typeid(*data1cast).name() << endl; // data1cast(typeid): class Dog
        (*data1cast).WriteData(formatter); // "Animal is doing something"

        ((Dog*)Data[1])->WriteData(formatter); // "Dog is doing something"
    }
};

struct Animal {
    virtual ~Animal() = default;

    template<typename Formatter>
    void WriteData(Formatter formatter) {
        formatter.Write("Animal is doing something");
    }
};

struct Dog : Animal {
    template<typename Formatter>
    void WriteData(Formatter formatter) {
        formatter.Write("Dog is doing something");
    }
};

int main(void) {
    Array<Animal*> arr;
    arr.Data[0] = new Animal();
    arr.Data[1] = new Dog();

    Writer writer;
    arr.WriteData(writer);

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Data[0](typeid): struct Animal
Data[1](typeid): struct Dog
Animal is doing something
Animal is doing something
data1cast(typeid): struct Dog
Animal is doing something
Dog is doing something
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Templates and virtuals [cannot be mixed](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_template#Member_function_templates):

```
template<typename Formatter>
virtual void WriteData(Formatter formatter);
```

would be an invalid declaration.

> A member function template cannot be virtual, and a member function template in a derived class cannot override a virtual member function from the base class.

You have several options here depending on what flexibility you want to achieve and what other constraints you have. For example:

**1.**

You can introduce an abstract class `Formatter`:

```
struct Formatter {
    virtual ~Formatter() = default;
    virtual void Write(const std::string&) = 0;
};

struct Writer : Formatter {
    void Write(const std::string& data) override {
        std::cout << data << std::endl;
    }
};
```

and make `WriteData` a non-template:

```
struct Animal {
    virtual ~Animal() = default;

    virtual void WriteData(Formatter& formatter) {
        formatter.Write("Animal is doing something");
    }
};

struct Dog : Animal {
    void WriteData(Formatter& formatter) override {
        formatter.Write("Dog is doing something");
    }
};
```

**2.**

Make `WriteData` a non-virtual template that calls virtual member functions to get information that should be passed to `Formatter`:

```
struct Writer {
    template<class T>
    void Write(const T& data) {
        std::cout << data << std::endl;
    }
};

struct Animal {
    virtual ~Animal() = default;

    template<class Formatter>
    void WriteData(Formatter formatter) {
        formatter.Write(MyName() + " is doing something");
    }

    virtual std::string MyName() {
        return "Animal";
    }
};

struct Dog : Animal{
    virtual std::string MyName() {
        return "Dog";
    }
};
```

**3.**

Don't use virtuals at all, dispatch `WriteData` call at compile-time. Instead of array use `std::tuple` to store distinct types:

```
struct Writer {
    template<class T>
    void Write(const T& data) {
        std::cout << data << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename... Types>
struct Array {
    std::tuple<Types...> Data;

    Array(Types... data) : Data(std::move(data)...) {}

    template<typename Formatter>
    void WriteData(Formatter formatter) {
        std::get<0>(Data).WriteData(formatter);
        std::get<1>(Data).WriteData(formatter);
    }
};

struct Animal {
    template<typename Formatter>
    void WriteData(Formatter formatter) {
        formatter.Write("Animal is doing something");
    }
};

struct Dog { // can be derived from Animal, but here it doesn't matter
    template<typename Formatter>
    void WriteData(Formatter formatter) {
        formatter.Write("Dog is doing something");
    }
};

int main() {
    Array<Animal, Dog> arr{Animal(), Dog()};   // <...> can be omitted in C++17

    Writer writer;
    arr.WriteData(writer);
}
```

**4.**

You can use `dynamic_cast` inside `if-else` branches:

```
struct Writer {
    template<class T>
    void Write(const T& data) {
        std::cout << data << std::endl;
    }
};

struct Animal {
    virtual ~Animal() = default;

    template<typename Formatter>
    void WriteData(Formatter formatter) {
        formatter.Write("Animal is doing something");
    }
};

struct Dog : Animal {
    template<typename Formatter>
    void WriteData(Formatter formatter) {
        formatter.Write("Dog is doing something");
    }
};

template<typename Type>
struct Array {
    Type Data[2];

    template<typename Formatter>
    void WriteData(Formatter formatter) {
        for (auto d : Data) {
            if (auto dog = dynamic_cast<Dog*>(d))
                dog->WriteData(formatter);
            else
                d->WriteData(formatter);
        }
    }
};
```

This design is pretty bad. Each time you modify the hierarchy of animals, you have to update `Array::WriteData`.

Comment: Suggestion 3 seems like an interesting idea as I don't want my Writer to have a base class (1) and there is no guarantee that the data in WriteData may always be completely different (2)

The problem is that while I know Animal and Dog are values 0 and 1 in this example, I may not know that in the future so using the initializer list construction is not possible. I have tried to do an std::get(1) = Dog() set locally although that does not seem to be valid. Is there a way to do this without knowing the Array value types at construction?

Comment: @judeclarke, option 3 is purely compile-time. You have to know the types. `std::get<i>` accepts only compile-time constant as an index. If you don't know the types, then you need run-time dispatch. You either use `virtual` here of there, or write some `if-else` with `dynamic_cast<Derived>(base)` stuff. I will add it as an option 4.